# Swapping content of div, on click on image or iframe (Vimeo)

Tags: javascript, jquery, vimeo

I have some issue:

I have some container, and three elements below this div. Three elements are `images` or `iframe` with `vimeo` embedded `movie`.

In first case i have :

```
<div id="media-content">
  <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/1271?api=1" width="100%" height="400" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
</div>
```

And below:

```
<div class="media-list" id="media-list">
                <span> <?php echo $this->Html->image('placeholder/video2.jpg');?>  </span>
                <span> <?php echo $this->Html->image('placeholder/video3.jpg');?>  </span>
                <span>
                    <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/127561?api=1" width="100%" height="400" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
                </span>
            </div>
```

And Jquery:

```
var media = $('#media-list img');
    var mediaContainer = $('#media-content');
    $(media).on('click',function(e){
        var vals = $(this).parent().html();
        $(mediaContainer).html(vals);
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log (e.target);
    });
```

And now what this code does:

On clicking on `video2.jog` or `video3.jpg`, `iframe` in `<div id="media-content">` is replaced with this clicked image. And this is ok.

But i want to show `vimeo` movie `<div id="media-content">` on click at iframe inside.

So it's simple content swap, but the problem is, that i don't know how "transfer" vimeo iframe do another div, as clicking on it does nothing.

Thank You for any reply.

PS: To address this question, i send image, it shows 3 red spans and one big green div. CLicking on span should set his attr (in this case img).And this work, problem is,that clicking on vimeo span should open video in green div.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78CTN.png)

Comment: Means you want to put "media-content" in 3rd span iframe? what will be the first "media-content" after showing it in iframe will  it be hide? Or just be copied and cloned?

Comment: no metter what i click, i want to show clicked item in main div (id="media-content"). On images click, this work, but no effect on vimeo iframe. Copied / cloned is good to examine my problem :)

Comment: didn't  @lepanto answer worked?

Comment: No.It didn't help...

Comment: Ok, Please clarify your question so that it is easily understandable what you ware wanting.

Comment: At first this link is said "https://player.vimeo.com/video/127561?api=1"  video does not exist

Comment: Does $('#media-list img') select your iframe? I'm not sure that it does.

Comment: I think you couldn't still clarify your requirements.; Because there are two vimo iframe. Your image is saying that when you click on any span that is in media-list that will go in green div isn't it? But your description is fully reverse of the image. Because in your description I am understanding " <div id="media-content"> on click at iframe inside" that when you will click on  media-content that will go in span. Which one is correct please tell me. I am preparing your answer.

Comment: On main green div, there is a iframe, and should be replaced by clicked span, if clicked span is image, this image should be send to green div, but if click on span with vimeo, this vimeo should go to green big div....

Comment: It is tough to traverse and get iframe by jqury from two different host. I hvae done it by loading iframe from same host. And also did in a diffrent way.. You just need to put a simple character or another html element in the third span.. I am posting it :)

Comment: Thank You for Help, ill try !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the browser loads/makes ready the DOM then iframe isn't included instantly. For the shake javascript or jquery canot get the inside element of the iframe as DOM haven't it, rather javascript or jquery only get the iframe tag.This is a critical and great problem with jquery & iframe when iframe load thing from different domain/host.
You can also get the iframe element by getting the span with jquery. But for this you have to give the 3rd span a a div  and have to click on the div not on the iframe content to get desired  solution.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script> 
<div id="media-content">
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/1271?api=1" width="100%" height="400" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
</div> 
 <div class="media-list" id="media-list"> 
            <span> <?php echo $this->Html->image('placeholder/video2.jpg');?>  </span>
            <span> <?php echo $this->Html->image('placeholder/video3.jpg');?>  </span>

      <span >  
         <div style="border: 1px solid red; z-index:3;width:80px;height:80px;padding:30px;">
         <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/127561?api=1" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
         </div> 
     </span>   
 </div> 
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
var media = $('#media-list img');   
var mediaContainer = $('#media-content'); 
    $(media).on('click',function(e){ 
        var vals = $(this).parent().html();
        $(mediaContainer).html(vals); 
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log (e.target);
    }); 
var media2 = $('#media-list div');  
    $(media2).on('click',function(e){ 
        var vals = $(this).html();
        $(mediaContainer).html(vals).height("70%").width("70%");
         e.preventDefault();
        console.log (e.target);
    }); 
 });
</script>
```

Comment: With pleasure, but i have to small repotation, when i will have enaught, i will not forget about You :).Thanks.